# How to play files from external storage to MediaPlayer with SeekBars?

Tags: uri, adapter, seekbar

I have a problem with my MediaPlayer. I wrote the permissions for reading the external storage but I can't play files when I click on them.
I also have two seeksbars, one for the volume and one for song progression.
The errors is on MediaPlayer.create(), but without this function, the app crashed.

'$' `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seekbar);

```
   // mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, ); <br>
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); <br>
    int volumeMax = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); <br>
    int volumeCorrente = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); <br>

    SeekBar controlloVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar); <br>
    controlloVolume.setMax(volumeMax); <br>
    controlloVolume.setProgress(volumeCorrente); <br>` '$'
```